# Stop an interval of a controller on navigating to another site

Tags: angularjs, intervals, angularjs-controller

In my application I am constantly updating displayed data which changes on the server using an interval, which loads whenever the controller loads. The controller loads together with the function in the interval when I navigate to a specific site and I would like it to stop when I navigate to another. The problem is that after some time of usage of the site, I end up with a bunch of intervals running and it just appears nasty. Here is the code of the controller:

```
angular
.module('myApp')
.controller('TaxiesController', ['$scope', '$location', '$routeParams', '$route', 'dataFactory', '$interval', function ($scope, $location, $routeParams, $route, dataFactory, $interval) {
    console.log('TaxiesController loaded')
    var cancel = {
        name: 'Preklic',
        price: 500
    }
    $scope.taxies = [];
    $scope.taxi = {};
    $scope.taxi.history = [];
    taxi = {}
    taxi.history = [];

    $scope.getTaxies = () => {
        dataFactory.getTaxies().then(function (response) {
            $scope.taxies = response.data;
        });
    }

    $scope.getTaxi = () => {
        var id = $routeParams.id;
        dataFactory.getTaxi(id).then(function (response) {
            $scope.taxi = response.data;
        });
    }

    $scope.removeTaxi = (id) => {
        dataFactory.removeTaxi(id).then(function (response) {});
    }

    $scope.getTotal = (taxi) => {
        var total = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < taxi.history.length; i++) {
            var rent = taxi.history[i];
            if (rent.price) total += rent.price;
        }
        return total;
    }

    $scope.disableTaxi = (taxi, id) => {
        taxi.drivable = false;
        dataFactory.updateTaxi(id, taxi).then(function (response) {
            $scope.taxi = response.data;
            $route.reload();
        })
    }

    $scope.cancelTaxi = (taxi, id) => {
        console.log('cancelling..')
        taxi.available = true;
        taxi.history.unshift(cancel);
        dataFactory.updateTaxi(id, taxi).then(function (response) {});
    }

    var updateTaxies = () => {
        console.log('Checking rent length')
        dataFactory.getTaxies().then(function (response) {
            $scope.taxies = response.data;
        });
    }

    $interval(updateTaxies, 2000);
}]);
```

Comment: $scope.onDestroy(() => {$interval.cancel(yourInterval)})

Comment: Where do I add this? And what is the onDestroy function?

Comment: Generally you don't need to do anything like that. *The problem is that after some time of usage of the site, I end up with a bunch of intervals running and it just appears nasty* - how is it possible if this is another website? (considering that it was opened in same window).

Answer (score 0):

Just add this inside the controller:

```
var intervalListener = $interval(updateTaxies, 2000);
$scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
    $interval.cancel(intervalListener);
});
```

$destroy is an event that will be fired when a scope is being destroyed. Here is the [doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#event-$destroy) about it

Comment: Hmmm, the interval doesn't stop, apparently because when I switch sites, the same controller is used on all of them. Would I have to separate controllers for different sites in order for this to work?

Comment: I'm not sure that that destroy event is triggered on navigation.

Comment: Normally you use a different controller for each view and if you need communication within the controllers you use services.
If you are using only one controller i would use a factory for the interval that can be canceld and startet from the router. or you can watch for route changes

Comment: @Vid seems like you do not know what 'site' means -- even when you navigate to another page (or/and another site), all js objects are destroyed completely. This is different from angular navigation (i.e. site.com/books -> site.com/library) that is not navigation from browser point of view.

Comment: What is it then? Just changing templates in the view?